# Connecting MySQL to Ruby on Rails - ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had MySQL Workbench installed with an existing database, ready to go. I installed Rails and configured my **database.yml** file to read:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: unibands
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  host: localhost
```

However, when navigating to anywhere on `http://localhost:3000`, I am greeted with the error: `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished`

The 'full' error in Terminal reads:

```
Started GET "/pins/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-20 19:47:12 +0000

ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished):
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cache_settings'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__4325676049139756285__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (14.3ms)
```

I am on a Mac (OS Mavericks) with Rails 4.0.2

If I change the connection to the default sqlite3, it renders the page. So it's definitely a problem with my DB connection. I am new to Rails, so it may be a simple fix, but nothing seems to be working for me.

Comment: are you using MAMP or WAMP by chance? if yes make sure you put the correct socket

Comment: Did you create the MySQL database? Also, are you able to connect to the database with such credentials?

Comment: I'm not using MAMP. If I open MySQL Workbench, I can access the DB right there and query it. Is there a socket I need for Rails to work with this?

Comment: `$ bundle exec rake db:create` it should help

Comment: Any luck with this so far?

Comment: I get 'Could not locate Gemfile' with rake. I have the rake gem installed though.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo, do you have a `Gemfile` in your project root?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MAMP add the following in your database.yml

```
socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Mysql by default installs socket in /tmp/mysql.soc
so try because you are not running MAMP

```
socket: /tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: I am not using MAMP. If I need some kind of socket, where could I obtain this file?

Comment: run % mysqladmin variables

Comment: you can also type -a mysql to see where mysql is located

Comment: $ -a mysql ? It says: -bash: -a: command not found (in Terminal).

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo, what OS are you on?

Comment: `type -a mysql` is what @SamD meant, since you are using bash `which mysql` would work as well.

Comment: Yes I did type -a mysql and that was the error that arrived. I am using a Mac on Mavericks OS.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to provide a socket to your MySQL installation. First, find your MySQL install path by issuing the following from command line:

```
which mysql
```

Then, add the returned path as the socket in your `database.yml` file:

```
# db/database.yml
development:
  socket: /path/to/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Restart your webserver to reload your configuration files, and the problem should be resolved.